# Why is 3 a bad constant in the Vitali covering lemma?

Tags: measure-theory, mg.metric-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

Hi,

recently I had to do with the Hardy-Littlewood maximal function and we used there the Vitali covering lemma with constant 5. Then, given an advice, I proved it with constant k>3. But I cannot find an counterexapmle why 3 is not enough (it is enough in the finite version of the lemma).
Has anyone seen such an example?

Answer (score 5):

An example in $\mathbb{R}$ was posted by [Oded Schramm](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/schramm/) in May 2008 on the [discussion page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk%3AVitali_covering_lemma) of the Wikipedia article on the Vitali covering lemma.  Namely, consider $\{B(x,r):|x|<1/2\text{ and }|x|<r<(|x|+1)/3\}$.

Comment: Whilst questions that are answered on Wikipedia pages are often considered a little weak for MO, I think that if it's answered on the _discussion_ page then that constitutes "hard to find" and makes it okay!  (Assuming that the level of mathematics is reasonable, which I'm not in a position to judge on this one.)

Comment: I thought it was an interesting question, and it did take some work to find a counterexample.  The level is hard for me to gauge; verifying that this is a counterexample is basic, but not everyone would quickly come up with it in the first place.  I'll defer to others to judge whether this is reasonable.

Comment: I think this is interesting and very reasonable, just for the record. In fact, I'm a bit surprised this is in question.